# Continuous downvote on some questions at a time

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Yesterday I found the reputation changed on my account.

I checked in the reputation bar. Then I found that my questions got downvotes at a seconds gap.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/33000/teja-bhagavan-kollepara?tab=reputation

Comment: someone has some issue with you then

Comment: Contact the mods, on other SE sites they tend to reverse these things, as it tends to be against the rules.

Comment: @Teja Bhagavan Kollepara, we are looking this downvotes and will get back to you.

Comment: @AmitBera, Hi, Okay sure please check thanks

Comment: @MarshallTigerus, Hello dear. Thanks for the followup. One of the moderator responded.

Answer (score 7):

Teja, we have checked the activity on your account, we don't find enough proof of targetting down votes over your account and also, does not find this type of downvote activity over your account at past also. So, we don't take any action right now.
But, We still observing over your account and will take the right action, if anything comes at rader.

Comment: I also checked the same thing and can confirm that I came up with the same result.

Comment: Yeah Okay, thanks for the update. #Amit and @Marius